# Advanced Excel Search and Sorting

Tags: sorting, excel-formula

I have a incredibly large spreadsheet that lists details for the computers in my company's inventory. We need to know how many systems we have that are x years old. I was able to sort it by model but because the model names are wildly different it didn't help much. For example, one model name is

13-inch MacBook Pro (2011)

And another is

13-inch Retina MacBook Pro (Mid 2017)

The only constant value in the parentheses is the year at the end. I'm trying to write a formula that will spit out how many of each system there are. We need to know how many are 2011 computers, how many are 2017, etc. We are fine with grouping up "Early, Mid, Late" since we just need a year separation but those terms don't show up in every cell throwing my math off. The rows don't have to be sorted, I just need a count.

Comment: so: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"*2011*")`?

Answer (score 0):

My plan of attack would be to first, convert the spreadsheet into a table using Insert > Table... this enables Excel to manage calculating columns for you.

The following assumes that the cell at the top of your list contains the word "Detail".

Second, I would make a new column at the far right with an equation like this:

```
=mid([@Detail], find(")",[@Detail])-4, 4)
```

...and I would tune the "Find" function and the "mid" function until it gives me just the year.

Third, sort the entire table by this new column.  Tada!

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the data to column A. Cells A1 to A1000 in my Example.

In Enter the years in column C. Cells C2 to C20 in my example.

In cell D2, enter the following Array Formula, and drag it down.

**=SUM(IFERROR(IF(VALUE(LEFT(RIGHT($A$1:$A$1000,5),4))=C2,1,0),"-"))**

**Array Formulas** are entered using **Control + Shift + Enter**, instead of Enter.

The Formula takes the last 5 characters of all entries in the column A. Then it takes the first 4 characters of this new text (to eliminate the closing bracket) and converts the text entries to numerical values. It matches each entry with the year in column C, and totals the matches.

I hope this solves your problem.

Regards,

Vijaykumar Shetye,

Spreadsheet Excellence,

Panaji, Goa India